# std::shared_mutex не является членом std?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

Есть проект на 2015 студии. Сейчас установил 19 студию и при сборке появляется ругань на "std::shared_mutex не является членом std". #include  есть. чем лечится?

Comment: в VS2015 надо использовать std::shared_timed_mutex

Answer (score 2):

`std::shared_mutex` является частью с++17. 
В студии для использования даного функционала необходимо включить поддержку 17-го стандарта:

**Project->Properties->C++->Language->C++ language standard = ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)**

Конечо же не забыть:

```
#include <shared_mutex>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но во вкладке Language->C++ не нашел упоминания про стандарт. 
вот скрин [url=https://radikal.ru][img]https://a.radikal.ru/a04/2003/d5/778c0f514eb0.png[/img][/url]

Comment: @КонстантинАлександрович вставьте ссылку нормально

Comment: Да, судя по рисунку, что то пошло не так. Там нет возможности выбрать стандарт

Comment: @КонстантинАлександрович, к сожалению нет возможности проверить на 2019й студии, может кто-то подтянется

Answer (score 1):

shared_mutex появился в с++17. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что студия 2015, которая выпущена в 2014 (когда только появился с++14) знает о нем (бывают и исключения конечно).

Как лечить? перейти на 2017 или 2019 студию. Или использовать свеженький clang.

Если это не подходит - можно сделать и свой shared_mutex.

Comment: Так я и использую 2019 студию)

Comment: то есть, хотите сказать, что в 2015 было, а в 2019 уже нет?